# Getting the error (System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.')

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

This is my code:

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True"); //datasource 
            
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[register]
           ([firstname], [lastname], [address], [gender], [email], [phone], [username], [password])
                                      VALUES ('" + txtFname.Text + "', '" + txtLname.Text + "', '" + txtAdd.Text + "', '" + cmbGender.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', '" + txtEmail.Text + "', '" + txtPhone.Text + "', '" + txtUser.Text + "', '" + txtPass.Text + "')");

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
                
    MessageBox.Show("Registered successfully"); //end of code 
}
```

This code is supposed to add values into a database table from Windows form but its giving this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Comment: WARNING! This code is *wide* open to SQL injection attacks! You ***NEED*** to fix that a *properly* **parametrise** your queries. *Never* inject (unsanitised) strings into your SQL queries.

Comment: As Larnu said same thing, but also your building a string so if the fields are blank, null, or have quotes in them, it could cause issues.  You should use paramaters and validate the data from your form before trying to send to DB.

Also you can view the query in the cmd text to see if it is formatted incorrectly by pasting into SQL

Comment: You need to **connect** your `SqlCommand` to a `SqlConnection` - I typically use this constructor:  `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (query, conn);` - you didn't do that, so your `SqlCommand` isn't associated with any connection to a database - that's the error you're getting